# How do you wait for shadow elements in selenium?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome

This more a generic question related to handling shadow elements. I currently came across a situation where i need to handle nested shadow elements and some of the deep lying elements are dynamic. I can interact with these elements by expanding each of the roots and navigating through them. As none of selenium explicit waits work when you are dealing with shadow elements which are dynamic.

There are some nested shadow elements which appear on user actions like 'click'. In these cases how do you wait for an element which is not present in the DOM at the time you begin your wait? Try/Catch is difficult because you need to know which nested shadow root loads slow.

Comment: use `WebDriverWait`

Comment: That doesn't help in this case for 2 reasons
1)Element is dynamically added to DOM
2)Element is in nested shadow roots

I could use try catch and iterate it but it becomes clumsy with nested shadow root elements

Also Webdriverwait would throw No Such Element Exception for these elements

Comment: Can you find them in chrome elements panel? You can search for elements there with css (ctrl+f).